# Unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': LibreSSL SSL_connect

Tags: git, homebrew

I am unable to install Home-brew in my MacBook Pro (Catalina OS). I have tried using the current command in the home-brew website

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

I get past the first stage, but get the following git error after[image]

Comment: This is a bit of a long shot based on a similar StackOverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987512/ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-github-com443), but try to run `networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi` and give it another try.

Answer (score 5):

Set your DNS Server to **8.8.8.8**

Comment: This worked for me, I recently clean installed macOS Monterey and forgot about this setting. Homebrew installations works now.

Comment: How enable DNS in mac? PS: I an new to mac.

Answer (score 4):

I rename the .gitconfig file to another and re-install brew, it works for me.
`mv ~/.gitconfig ~/.backgitconfig`

Rename back after install brew successfully.
`mv .backgitconfig .gitconfig`

Answer (score 1):

Set your DNS Server to 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS)

Go to Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Click on on your wifi connection or ethernet (in case of LAN) > Properties > Double Click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) > Set Preferred DNS to 8.8.8.8 and Alternate DNS to 8.8.4.4 > Select Validate Settings on Exit > Click Ok.

This will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens because of the wrong IP/DNS settings. Checking the below places might help resolve the issue:

1. Make sure you are using a common [public DNS server](https://www.lifewire.com/free-and-public-dns-servers-2626062). How to [check the DNS server you are using](https://techwiser.com/check-your-dns-server/) depends on your operating system. Moreover, if you are using a VPN client and it has a DNS configuration, check that setting too.
2. Check if there is an IP address associated with GitHub in the system's [hosts](https://linuxhandbook.com/etc-hosts-file/) file. In Linux and macOS you may use `sudo vi /etc/hosts`. If there is one, turn that line into a comment by adding `#` at the beginning of the line. Save, exit, and check if you see that error again. **Do step 3 only if you are still getting the same error.**
3. Go to `https://www.ipaddress.com`, search for `github.com`, and add its IP address at the bottom of `/etc/hosts` file like this example: `140.82.114.4 github.com`.

Hope this helps.